# builder: from FutureBuilder doesn't works

Tags: flutter, builder, sqflite

When I try to use the FutureBuilder in this case only makes the future: but does not goes to the builder: for any reason that I can not find. I can not check if it hasdata or not. I give you the code here.

```
ConstrainedBox(
constraints: BoxConstraints(
  maxWidth: ajuste.width*0.74,
  minWidth: ajuste.width*0.74
),
child: CupertinoButton(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: ajuste.sp(1.8)),
  color: Colors.pinkAccent,
  onPressed: (){
    compruebaDatos();
  },
  child: Text(
    AppLocalizations.of(context).translate('entrar'),
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: ajuste.sp(2.4)
    ),
  ), 
),
),

compruebaDatos() {
FutureBuilder<List<Usuario>>(
  future: DatabaseProvider.db.getAllUsers(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Usuario>> snapshot){
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data !=null) {
        print('Datos nulos');
        return HomePage();
      }else{
        print('Datos recogidos');
        return HomePage();
      }
    }else{
      print('No aparece nada');
      return HomePage();
    }
  },
);
}
```

And the future inside a class to connect sqflite

```
Future<List<Usuario>> getAllUsers() async {
final db = await database;
var response = await db.query("Usuarios");
List<Usuario> list = response.isNotEmpty
  ? response.map((c) => Usuario.fromMap(c)).toList()
  : []; 
return list;
```

}

Thank you

Comment: Did it print out any value?

Comment: [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) is widget and builder will be called when the widget is rendered. If you want to go to a different screen, you can use [navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

`FutureBuilder` is a `Widget`. You shouldn't use it in `compruebaDatos()`.

Inside `onPressed` you should call `DatabaseProvider.db.getAllUsers()` directly and process it response and call `Navigator.of(context).push(...)` to go to another page.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but How I can check if the List<usuario> has data?. That's why I tried to use the FutureBuilder.

Comment: I did it but still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I change the FutureBuilder inside a children and check if length from snapshot is bigger than 0

```
Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          FutureBuilder<List<Usuario>>(
                            future: DatabaseProvider.db.getAllUsers(),
                            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Usuario>> snapshot){
                              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                if (snapshot.data.length == 0) {
                                  tieneDatos=false;
                                }else{
                                  tieneDatos=true;
                                  Usuario item = snapshot.data[0];
                                  print(item.usuario);
                                }
                              }
                              return Container();
                            },
                          ),
```